# How can I show that the transformation of a function is a linear operator?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, linear-transformations

I have the linear transformation

$$T : P_3[x] → P_3[x]$$,

defined as

$$T(p(x)) = xp'(x) − 2p(x)$$ and I need to show that it is a linear operator.

So I want to show that $$T(p(x_1) + T(p(x_2)) = T(p(x_1) + p(x_2))$$.

The L.H.S is simple - > $$x_1(p'(x1))-2(p(x1)) + x_2(p'(x_2))-2(p(x_2))$$.

The R.H.S is trickier as any variation I try to format as something identical as T(p(x)) leads to solutions where the sides are not equal. I have tried taking

$$h(x) = p(x_1) + p(x_2)$$

And solving $T(h(x))$ and replacing afterwards but I'm not sure if something like that is conceptually correct, nor did it lead to a correct answer.

I am just looking for what the first step would be in solving the R.H.S

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: forgot to edit properly, fixed thanks

Comment: Differentiation is a linear operation, as is multiplication by a scalar or indeterminate, and $T$ is just a composite of these operations hence is linear.

Answer (score 1):

You have\begin{align}T\bigl(p_1(x)+p_2(x)\bigr)&=T\bigl((p_1+p_2)(x)\bigr)\\&=x(p_1+p_2)'(x)-2(p_1+p_2)(x)\\&=x\bigl(p_1'(x)+p_2'(x)\bigr)-2p_1(x)-2p_2(x)\\&=xp_1'(x)-2p_1(x)+p_2'(x)-2p_2(x)\\&=T\bigl(p_1(x)\bigr)+T\bigl(p_2(x)\bigr).\end{align}